# Inverse of a product in semigroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

*Disclaimer. The following might end up being a stupid question*

Let $S$ be a regular semigroup i.e for every $s\in S$ we can write $s=sas$ for some $a\in S$ (called an inverse of $s$).

> Do we know how to compute explicitly an inverse of a product? That is given $s=sas$ and $t=tbt$, can we tell what an inverse of $st$ would be?

Some attempts go as follows
$$st(btsa)st = s(tbt)(sas)t = sstt =st \Leftarrow s,t\in E(S) $$
We could also do
$$ st(bca)st = (sas)t(bca)s(tbt) = s(astb)c(astb)t = s(astb)t = (sas)(tbt) = st $$
We've assumed $c\in V(astb)$, which is provided by regularity, and the arithmetic checks out, but I'm not entirely convinced by this.

Comment: In the first one, why should $s$ and $t$ be in $E(S)$ (assuming that means the set of idempotents of $S$)? Or are you pointing out (correctly) that that's only valid for $s$ and $t$ in $E(S)$? (We know that $sa, as, tb, bt \in E(S)$, but not $s$ or $t$).  But the second proof is indeed correct. Any particular reason you're not convinced by it?

Comment: @M.Vinay In the first one if we assumed $s,t$ were idempotents, then we'd have our inverse. Notice that in that case, there is no magical $c$. For the second one I just tried to fit something between $st(\ldots)st$ and it checked out, but it now relies on some new $c$. I get the feeling like I'm cheating, because the goal is to find an explicit inverse, however, $c$ merely invokes regularity, we don't know what it looks like.

Comment: Well the reverse is true. In the first case you've assumed special properties for $s$ and $t$, which may not hold [to give a trivial and extreme example: a group is a regular semigroup, but the only idempotent element is the identity]. In the second case, you _know_ that such a $c$ exists because of regularity, so there's no cheating there. In fact, we should somewhat expect that the generalised inverse of $st$ might depend on some completely new element other than $s$ and $t$ — i.e., we should expect the involvement of some such $c$.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking about this again, and I see that I'd lost track of the true meaning of the problem when we discussed this two days back. You're right, since we don't know what $c$ is, knowing a generalised inverse of $st$ in terms of the unknown $c$ is as good [bad] as saying "Let $d$ be the generalised inverse of $st$".

Comment: However, maybe what you've written is not completely useless just because of that. The problem is now reduced t figuring out a generalised inverse of $astb$. That looks like a more complicated term than $st$, but I don't think we can immediately rule out the possibility of this being an easier problem.

Comment: @M.Vinay It would clearly be too much to ask to be able to give explicitly every inverse of a fixed element. However, an explicit example of an inverse of a product doesn't seem (entirely) unreasonable.

Comment: Yes. My intuition refuses to admit the possibility of their being a $c$ defined in terms of $s$, $t$, $a$, $b$ such that $stcst = st$, since $s$ and $t$ are completely arbitrary (so it seems impossible that $tcs$ could "vanish"). Still we can try.

Comment: One lead I'm investigating right now is using _reflexive_ generalised inverses of $s$ and $t$. That is, $q$ such $sqs = s$ and $qsq = q$ (and similarly one for $t$). If $a$ is a generalised inverse of $s$, then $q = asa$ is a reflexive generalised inverse of $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find such an explicit inverse in general and essentially because of what has been said already by M. Vinay on 24.03, the first comment. Also, consider the simpler case with inverse semigroups. There the inverse of a product is very simple but in a regular semigroup, there is no *the inverse* but the set of inverses and this leaves everything open, at least up to the precision of that set of inverses $V(s)$ for any $s\in S$.

More precisely, I think the originial question *is equivalent* of asking: given any $s\in S$, give explicitly the inverse of $s$.

Proof.

One way is obvious: if one can give an explicit inverse for any $s\in S$ then this also holds for $st\in S$ for any $s,t\in S$.

The reverse implication: if one can give explictly an inverse of $st$ for any $s,t\in S$ then just note that if $s\in S$ is arbitrary and $s'\in V(s)$ then $s=ss's=s(s's)$ and explicit inverse of this can be given by assumption. QED.

I would also like to give something that may give you hints in this direction. In Howie's "Fundamentals of Semigroup Theory" (1995), there is Theorem 2.5.4 on page 60:

Let $a,b\in S$, where $S$ is a regular semigroup. Let $a'\in V(a)$, $b'\in V(b)$ and $g\in S(a'a,bb')$. Then $b'ga'\in V(ab)$.

Here $S(e,f)$ (for any two idempotents $e,f\in E(S)$) is the *sandwich set* defined as follows: $S(e,f)=\{g\in V(ef)\cap E:ge=fg=g\}$ and has an alternative description $S(e,f)=\{g\in E:ge=fg=g, egf=ef\}$.

So considering the original question, this $b'ga'$ is one example of an inverse of $ab\in S$ and one can try to improve this fundamental result or prove that this can't be improved any further, or can show similar connection using some other set than the sandwich set.

One more comment. Considering any regular semigroup, one can use Nambooripad's general description of regular semigroups but I'm not sure where this really leads to or if it gives any useful information.